# iOS, how to avoid app keeping long alive?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I searched on Google and find nothing helpful. And it seems no iOS SDK to configure how long the app can keep alive.

For example, I want the app to keep alive for 1 day.
If after 2 ~ 3 days, and user touches the App icon, and restore it back to foreground state. I want it to behave the same as restarting the App.

Due to some internal state, memory cache is in an error state, and user isn't aware of something wrong, then bad thing will happen. Some functions do not work, and bad input leads to worse output.

So, how to configure a maximum alive time for app ?

Comment: You can't define how long app should remain in background. 
But If you want that app should behave like restarting app when ever click on App Icon, You can achieve that.

Comment: But this behaviour will continue while user leave app in background for 1 sec or 1 day or more. So basically whenever user will move app to background, and click again on App, app will restart.

Comment: How to achieve like restarting app when click on App icon ? Err... Info.plist configuration ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'keep the app alive'?  Do you mean that if the user starts the app after less than 2 days (for example) it starts where they left off but longer than that and it resets to some initial state?

Comment: @AechoLiu Yes, with info.plist configuration

Comment: In my encountered case, the app lives too long (about 1 day), and some internal status went wrong. And a game I love, Clash Royale, it will restart if I leave the game after 10 minutes. But if I leave that game in short time, it won't restart.

Answer (score 1):

The App lifecycle shouldn't work like this. When the App is brought from the background, the App should check whether the state of the App is correct or not. If not, reset/rectify/restore the status. You should NOT rely on keeping the app "alive, as the user can kill the App at any time.

Comment: I hope user avoid keeping the app alive. The App should NOT be alive after 2 ~ 3 days. I hope it can be restarted.

Comment: Thank you about reminding me, I should check something when App is brought from the background. I could check a timeout, and let it behave like restarting at that point.